# How to write a MouseListener for JavaFX

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, java-8, mouse, mouselistener

I want to write a little game where I shoot from an object to a specific direction on a JavaFX Panel using my mouse position.

I want to turn a `Line` in the direction where my Mouse is.

```
Line line = new Line(startPosX, startPosY, mouseDirectionX, mouseDirectionY);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a MOUSE_MOVED event filter like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = new Pane();
            Line line = new Line( 400,200,400,200);
            root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
                line.setEndX(e.getSceneX());
                line.setEndY(e.getSceneY());
            });
            root.getChildren().add(line);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you want the line to be limited in length, you'll have to do the proper calculations of course via the angle.